# Хостинг для Java-приложения: помогите разобраться

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, сервер, tomcat

Написал простенький Java-сервер на сокетах. Запускаю в Eclipse - всё хорошо, работает, взаимодействует с клиентом.

Сейчас хочу разместить сервер на хостинге, выбрал в  качестве площадки бесплатный http://www.openshift.com, но я совершенно не знаком с технологией развёртывания java-приложения на внешнем хостинге. Почитал статьи, там, в основном, речь идёт о веб-приложениях. У меня же просто программа, которая слушает один порт, принимает сокеты и отдаёт.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой нелегкой темой, может быть, почитать что-то посоветуете?

А то я смотрю: Jboss, Tomcat... Это вообще по моей теме?

Comment: На OpenShift нельзя получить рут права в том виде, в котором они нужны для установки Java-машины и вообще свободного доступа к системе.
huffman правильно сказал: нужен VPS. Нашёл бесплатный вариант на http://www.host1free.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Купите VPS [тут](https://www.digitalocean.com) и ставьте на сервер что хотите. Вот тут описано как поставить томкат и настроить жаву: [How To Install Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Почитаю про Tomcat.

Comment: для запуска приложения с сокетам вам tomcat не нужнет. установите на vps java jre и запускайте скомпилированный код. не забудь настроить iptables открыв порт по которому будет осуществляться подключение к вашему java-серверу.

Comment: А облачная платформа для таких задач не подойдёт? Хотел воспользоваться бесплатным облачным сервисом. Вроде как много общего с VPS

Comment: облачная платформа это маркетинг. что за платформа, ссылку дайте.

Comment: www.openshift.com
Там система картриджей и можно подключить Tomcat

Comment: я вижу там есть доступ по ssh наверное и root доступ тоже есть. думаю можно и на этой облачной платформе запустить ваш java-сервер.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, разъяснили мои сомнения.
Позвольте еще спросить: на openshift мне предлагают выбрать сервис, который будет обслуживать моё приложение:
JBoss Application Server 7
Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)
Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)
CapeDwarf
JEE Full Profile on JBoss
Spring Framework on JBoss EAP6  

Мне выбрать Tomcat 7 и разбираться с ним или есть более перспективное решение?

Comment: В вашем случае совершенно все равно, что выбрать. выбирайте самый дешевый вариант так как сервер приложений вам не нужен.

я бы посоветовал взять vps у digitalocean самый дешевый 5$ в мес подробности тут https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing . Вы получаете виртуальный линуксовый сервер. далле как я уже озвучивал выше.